# How to find first message which is not deleted in Kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a topic and there are some messages in it. A part of messages was deleted after retention time was out including a message on which offset points and many messages after it.

How to find the oldest existing message in the topic? I heard there is some method in API but I can't find it. If someone knows how to do it, please help, 'cause I'm already tortured by searching it in the documentation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `kafka-console-consumer` with `--max-messages 1` and `--from-beginning` in order to fetch the oldest message:

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topic_name --from-beginning --max-messages 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`beginningOffsets()`](http://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#beginningOffsets-java.util.Collection-) method from the Consumer API to find the oldest message available.

For example:

```
Properties configs = new Properties();
configs.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
configs.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
configs.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

try (KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(configs);) {

    Map<TopicPartition, Long> offsets = consumer.beginningOffsets(Collections.singletonList(TP));
    System.out.println(offsets);
}
```

That will print something like:

> {offset-test-0=0}

In this example, offset 0 is the oldest offset available.